# When Changing an Opportunity Owner can an email notification be mandatory?

Tags: email, opportunity, notification, owner

Is it possible to make the email notification mandatory when changing the opportunity owner without having to tick the box, or have the box as default ticked?

Preferably without coding - If possible, No idea where to start with the coding side of things :)

Too many colleagues are changing owners without notifying meaning that work just doesn't get picked up.

As Always, appreciate any help you guys offer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BriZAAS) 'Under Product Team Review' and there seems to be fairly strong support for it so I hope this will be implemented in future as a native feature. The idea is generic so it cover opportunities, leads and other objects as well.

Until then, you'll need to rely either on writing an Apex trigger/ flow which detects this change and sends a email notification - but that would lead to duplicate notifications in case it's already checked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response - was waiting a while and was worried haha. I hope it does get implemented in ASAP - it's really frustrating. Also it's weird that for such an open platform there is not much you can do about the whole "Change Owner" Id like to be able to customize the email that is sent, send to multiple users with notes & of course make it mandatory to tick.. Point and click over programming any day for me at this present time in my Salesforce journey.